# Passing a group id to custom loss function in Keras R

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tf.keras, loss-function

I was hoping that someone might be able to give me a hand.

I've been using keras to model a disease risk factor in 11 different populations and am trying to create a custom loss function that is aware of these population groups.

Currently training the model with mse as the loss function, but I would like to encourage the model to condense the variation in its predictions for specific groups. Specifically, the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxbUt.png) shows model performance where each colour represents a different population group. As an example, the green group is much narrower than the blue and purple group, suggesting that the model has done a better job learning that group. I would like to create a loss function to explicitly encourage the model to condense variation on the x-axis, however, I'm having trouble passing group ids to the loss function back end.

Is anyone able to suggest a workaround? I'd be incredibly grateful for any help that you are kind enough to provide. Please let me know if you have any questions. Sorry that I can't provide any examples of what I've tried - this is my first time trying to write a custom loss function and I'm completely stumped ...

Harry